# Hooking into Windows File System and Insert Virtual File System

Tags: hook, virtualfilesystem

I'm working on an application similar to a program called [Mod Organizer](http://wiki.step-project.com/Guide:Mod_Organizer). Essentially what the program does is let people download and install mods to the game, Skyrim. However, Mod Organizer does something interesting; rather than install the mods directly to the game's data directory (like other mod managers), MO installs each mod to its own directory in some other arbitrary location and then loads all the mods together once the game launches. This is important because it makes mod managing much less of a hassle.

My question is: how might I create this on the fly file system or make Windows "pretend" a directory full of mod files is somewhere else.

At first I thought of creating symlinks with my code, but [This guide](http://wiki.step-project.com/Guide:Mod_Organizer_Advanced#The_virtual_filing_system) put me onto the trail of "hooking," and specifically recommended trying EasyHook. While I think can understand the underlying concept of hooking (essentially intercepting signals from the OS and redirecting them for whatever purpose), I don't really know how to make the hook actually redirect files.

If anyone knows a good resource for this kind of hooking or has better approach to my problem, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score -2):

What you have described in done with a filesystem filter driver. This driver intercepts requests to the filesystem and inserts additional information, such as tells the system about the files and directories which don't really exist on the disk. If the files are preset somewhere on the disk, the request can be simply redirected to the existing file or directory.

Filesystem filter driver is a kernel-mode driver, not easy to implement. You can use a pre-created driver that lets you perform tasks in user mode API, eg. our [CBFS Filter](https://www.callbacktechnologies.com/cbfsfilter/).